# is there any way i can apply another style on a styler in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, pandas-styles

I have NAN values in my dataframe columns and i need to replace it with empty string. I need to perform subtraction on these columns, so when replacing with empty string i am getting error:

> unsupported operand types for -:'str' and 'str'.

so while applying style to my dataframe i have added this line, and it is working as well:

```
df.style.set_na_rep('')
```

But when i am adding format function to the style, to concat '%' symbol in the columns, the NAN values are reappearing along withe the '%' symbol.

Then syntax is:

```
df = (df.style.apply(highlight_cells, axis = None).set_na_rep('')).format({'B':'{:}%','C':'{:}%'}).set_table_styles(...)
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab | 8.3% | 4.7% |
| cd | 9.0% | NAN% |
| ef | NAN% | NAN% |
| gh | NAN% | 13.9% |

can anyone please suggest, I am pretty new in pandas and dataframes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of pandas 1.3.0 `set_na_rep()` is deprecated and you should use `format(na_rep="xx")` instead.

If the values are truly missing, i.e. they are `pd.nan` and  `pd.isna(val)` returns `True` then the value will be substitututed for the display value of `na_rep`.

On the other hand if you have previously performed some manipulation and the value is a string representation of 'NAN', then this is not a missing value (it is a string), and the `na_rep` argument will have no effect.

Actually you can see the relevant issue to this here (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/40060) and the ultimate solution (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/40134)

Comment: It worked for me. Could you please also tell where can I learn more about it in depth. Thank you very much